# Disable Warning message in android

Tags: android

I am developing android application and I updated this application from to remote When I send push mesage it can be updated itself. Firstly I am deleting old application and then I am installing new application. When I delete old application it asks me Are you sure want to delete this app? I don't want to see this warning message Can I disable this message or Can I give automatically "Ok" answer in android code?

I use to delete app below code

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.androidhive.pushnotifications");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Comment: idk about you but this sounds like a bad idea and it sounds like you need root access. Actually, if you update using the same keystore values, you wouldn't have to delete the old one before installing the new one.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I disable this message?

No.

> Can I give automatically "Ok" answer in android code?

No.

Think about this from the user's perspective- do they want apps to be able to uninstall other applications without their knowledge or consent? While *you* may have good intentions, this opens up huge security holes that others could exploit.

If you are deploying this application in an environment that you control (e.g. an enterprise setting), then you may be able to root the devices to gain this control.

Comment: I will deploy it only a specific users I don't install app to google market.I don't want to that Users can not answer many warning messages